# Apposition von Aufzählung abgrenzen

Tags: apposition, list

Im folgenden Satz kann ich doch nur durch Kontext unterscheiden, ob das jetzt eine Apposition ist, also die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung Kitting und Line Stocking sind, oder ob das ganze eine Aufzählung ist, also "dies" für das danach folgende gilt.

Gibt es hier eine bessere Möglichkeit, um das gleich klar zu machen? Mein Ziel ist die Apposition, also die Grundprinzipien der MV sind das Kitting und LS. Wäre hier z.B. der Gebrauch eines Strichpunkts angebracht?

> Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung, das Kitting
> und das Line Stocking.

Comment: Einen Strichpunkt hätte ich nicht unbedingt genommen, aber ein Doppelpunkt scheint mir passend. Er erfüllt ca. die Funktion des _nämlich_ aus Hubert's Antwort.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Bitte verwende die Kommentarfunktion nicht um Antworten zu posten. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487

Comment: Jo eh, nur ist das obige meiner Meinung nach zu kurz als Antwort, sondern eher ein ergänzender Kommentar.

Answer (score 3):

Einmal so:

> Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung, nämlich für das Kitting und das Line Stocking.

Statt *»nämlich«* geht auch *»also«.*

Und dann so:

> Dies gilt: 1) für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung, 2) für das Kitting und 3) für das Line Stocking.

Comment: Dein zweites Beispiel funktioniert, das erste hat dasselbe Problem wie die ursprüngliche Formulierung - (*nämlich (K & LS)* oder *nämlich (K) & LS*.) Die von mir gesetzten Klammern sind aus dem Text nicht erkennbar.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist nicht einfach möglich, mathematisch genaue Schnitt- und Vereinigungsmengen in der Sprache mit einfachen Aufzählungen bzw Appositionen zu bilden - die Sprache kennt keine "harten" Operator-Prioritäten und auch keine Klammern.

Dein Satz

> Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung, das Kitting und das Line Stocking.

kann heißen (deine Begriffe offensichtlich abgekürzt):

```
GPDM & K & LS      (1)
(GPDM = (K)) & LS  (2)
GPDM = (K & LS)    (3)
```

Da "GPDM" im Plural steht, ist (2) unwahrscheinlich, aber möglich (hierbei wird - mathematisch ungenau - angenommen, dass (K) nur ein mögliches Beispiel für GDPM ist, LS aber nicht, andere Beispiele werden nicht genannt), sowohl (1) als auch (3) sind wahrscheinlicher.

Eine absolut konkrete Aussage lässt sich nur errichen, wenn der Satz, z.B. mit einem Nebensatz oder einem verlängerten Einschub,konkretisiert ist:

> Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung - das Kitting und das Line Stocking -, die in Kapitel xxx behandelt werden.

Hier ist klar: GPDM = K & LS - Der Einschub ist klar abgegrenzt, sowohl nach vorne als auch nach hinten (wichtig ist, dass nach dem Einschub noch etwas kommt, was die K & LS sozusagen "bündelt"). Der zweite Gedankenstrich vor dem Komma (der "eigentlich" unüblich ist) dient hier ebenfalls der Bündelung.

> Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung - z.B. das Kitting, aber auch für das Line Stocking.

Hier wird klar gemacht, dass (GDBM = (u.a. K), GDBM != LS). (Nicht deine gewünschte Aussage)

> Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung, aber auch das Kitting und das Line Stocking.

Auch hier ist klar, dass (GDBM != K), (GDBM != LS) (auch nicht deine Aussage)

Comment: Würde nicht auch "Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung - das Kitting und das Line Stocking." funktionieren bzw. kannst du kurz noch ein bisschen genauer erläutern warum es wichtig ist, "dass nach dem Einschub noch etwas kommt"? Und würde nicht auch ein "Dies gilt für die Grundprinzipien der Materialversorgung: das Kitting und das Line Stocking" funktionieren? Ich würde deine Antwort gerne als Lösung markieren, aber die Info fehlt mE noch.